# Помогите с картинкой от 450px

Tags: html, css, css3, html5

Начиная с 450px, картинка выходит за пределы экрана. Это можно предотвратить только с помощью @media? Если да, то просто напишите да). И не обращайте на мусор))

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="style.css">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="keywords" content="">
    <title>QBet.fun</title>
</head>
<body>

<!-----------------------ШАПКА----------------------->
    <div class="header">
        <div class="text_header">
<!----------------PC MENU---------------------------->
            <div class="header_logo"><a href=""><b>QBet</b></a></div>
            <div class="menu">
                <a href="">Мобильные</a>
                <a href="">Играть</a>
                <a href="">Советы</a>
                <a href="">Программы</a>
            </div>
<!----------------/PC MENU---------------------------->

<!----------------MOBILE MENU---------------------------->
    <div class="wrapper">
        <input type="checkbox" id="check-menu">
        <label for="check-menu"></label>
        <div class="burger-line first"></div>
        <div class="burger-line second"></div>
        <div class="burger-line third"></div>
        <div class="burger-line fourth"></div>
        <nav class="main-menu">
            <a href="#">Мобильные</a>
            <a href="#">Играть</a>
            <a href="#">Советы</a>
            <a href="#">Программы</a>
        </nav>
    </div>
<!----------------/MOBILE MENU---------------------------->
        </div>
    </div>
<!-----------------------/ШАПКА----------------------->

<div class="main">
    <div class="text_main">
        <p>Lorem Ipsum - это текст-"рыба", часто используемый в печати и вэб-дизайне. Lorem Ipsum является стандартной "рыбой" для текстов на латинице с начала XVI века. В то время некий безымянный печатник создал большую коллекцию размеров и форм шрифтов, используя Lorem Ipsum для распечатки образцов. Lorem Ipsum не только успешно пережил без заметных изменений пять веков, но и перешагнул в электронный дизайн. Его популяризации в новое время послужили публикация листов Letraset с образцами Lorem Ipsum в 60-х годах и, в более недавнее время, программы электронной вёрстки типа Aldus PageMaker, в шаблонах которых используется Lorem Ipsum.</p>
    </div>
<div class="banner">
  <a href="#"><img src="D:/Warhummer.jpg" alt="" width="468" height="60"></a>
</div>
</div>

<!------------------ПОДВАЛ------------------>
<div class="footer">QBet.fun
    <div class="s1">QBet@gmail.com</div>
</div>

</body>
</html>



*{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

a {
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
}

/*--------------PC MENU----------------*/
.header {
    background-color: #000;
    padding-right: 50px;
    padding-left: 50px;
    font-family: sans-serif;
}

.text_header {
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -moz-flex;
    display: -ms-flex;
    display: -o-flex;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    -ms-align-items: center;
    align-items: center;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    padding-top: 20px;
}

.header_logo {
    font-size: 26px;
}

.header_logo b:hover {
    color: #FA332DFF;
    transition: .3s;
}

.menu {
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -moz-flex;
    display: -ms-flex;
    display: -o-flex;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-end;
}

.menu a {
    margin-right: 60px;
    font-size: 20px;
}

.menu a:hover {
    color: #FA332DFF;
    transition: .3s;
}
/*--------------/PC MENU----------------*/
/*--------------MOBILE MENU----------------*/
.main-menu a:hover {
    background-color: #FA332DFF;
    transition: .3s;
}

.wrapper {
    display: none;
    width: 320px;
    background-color: #000;
    position: relative;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    height: 40px;
    font-family: 'Arial';
}

#check-menu{
    display: none;
}

label{
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    cursor: pointer;
    z-index: 2;
    line-height: 40px;
}

.burger-line{
    position: absolute;
    top: 8px;
    right: 10px;
    width: 35px;
    height: 2px;
    background-color: #fff;
    transition: .5s all;
}

.second, .third{
    top: 18px;
}

.fourth{
    top: 28px;
}

.main-menu{
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    transform: translateY(100%);
    max-height: 0;
    font-size: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    transition: .5s all;
}

.main-menu a{
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 10px;
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
    border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
    background-color: #000;
}

#check-menu:checked ~ .main-menu{
    max-height: 500px;
    font-size: 16px;
}

#check-menu:checked ~ .first{
    display: none;
}

#check-menu:checked ~ .second{
    transform: rotate(45deg);
}

#check-menu:checked ~ .third{
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
}

#check-menu:checked ~ .fourth{
    display: none;
}
/*--------------/MOBILE MENU----------------*/

.main {
    font-family: sans-serif;
    line-height: 24px;
    padding-top: 20px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    width: 90%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.text_main {
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}

/*----------------БАННЕР----------------*/
.banner {
    text-align: center;
}
/*----------------/БАННЕР----------------*/


/* Подвал сайта */
.footer {
    background-color: #000;
    color: #ccc;
    padding-top: 15px;
    padding-bottom: 15px;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    text-align: center;
}

.s1 {
    margin: 10px 0;
}



@media screen and (max-width: 992px) {
.wrapper {
  display: block;
}
.menu {
    display: none;
}
}

@media screen and (max-width: 360px) {
.header {
    padding-right: 15px;
    padding-left: 15px;
}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Зачем вам @media? Для картинок поставьте:

```
.text_main img,
.banner img {
   max-width: 100%;
}
```

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

a {
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.text_main img {
  max-width: 100%;
}


/*--------------PC MENU----------------*/

.header {
  background-color: #000;
  padding-right: 50px;
  padding-left: 50px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.text_header {
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -moz-flex;
  display: -ms-flex;
  display: -o-flex;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  -ms-align-items: center;
  align-items: center;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  padding-top: 20px;
}

.header_logo {
  font-size: 26px;
}

.header_logo b:hover {
  color: #FA332DFF;
  transition: .3s;
}

.menu {
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -moz-flex;
  display: -ms-flex;
  display: -o-flex;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}

.menu a {
  margin-right: 60px;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.menu a:hover {
  color: #FA332DFF;
  transition: .3s;
}


/*--------------/PC MENU----------------*/


/*--------------MOBILE MENU----------------*/

.main-menu a:hover {
  background-color: #FA332DFF;
  transition: .3s;
}

.wrapper {
  display: none;
  width: 320px;
  background-color: #000;
  position: relative;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  height: 40px;
  font-family: 'Arial';
}

#check-menu {
  display: none;
}

label {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  cursor: pointer;
  z-index: 2;
  line-height: 40px;
}

.burger-line {
  position: absolute;
  top: 8px;
  right: 10px;
  width: 35px;
  height: 2px;
  background-color: #fff;
  transition: .5s all;
}

.second,
.third {
  top: 18px;
}

.fourth {
  top: 28px;
}

.main-menu {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  transform: translateY(100%);
  max-height: 0;
  font-size: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: .5s all;
}

.main-menu a {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 10px;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
  background-color: #000;
}

#check-menu:checked~.main-menu {
  max-height: 500px;
  font-size: 16px;
}

#check-menu:checked~.first {
  display: none;
}

#check-menu:checked~.second {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

#check-menu:checked~.third {
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}

#check-menu:checked~.fourth {
  display: none;
}


/*--------------/MOBILE MENU----------------*/

.main {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  line-height: 24px;
  padding-top: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  width: 90%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.text_main {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}


/*----------------БАННЕР----------------*/

.banner {
  text-align: center;
}


/*----------------/БАННЕР----------------*/


/* Подвал сайта */

.footer {
  background-color: #000;
  color: #ccc;
  padding-top: 15px;
  padding-bottom: 15px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
}

.s1 {
  margin: 10px 0;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 992px) {
  .wrapper {
    display: block;
  }
  .menu {
    display: none;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 360px) {
  .header {
    padding-right: 15px;
    padding-left: 15px;
  }
}
```

```html
<!-----------------------ШАПКА----------------------->
<div class="header">
  <div class="text_header">
    <!----------------PC MENU---------------------------->
    <div class="header_logo"><a href=""><b>QBet</b></a></div>
    <div class="menu">
      <a href="">Мобильные</a>
      <a href="">Играть</a>
      <a href="">Советы</a>
      <a href="">Программы</a>
    </div>
    <!----------------/PC MENU---------------------------->

    <!----------------MOBILE MENU---------------------------->
    <div class="wrapper">
      <input type="checkbox" id="check-menu">
      <label for="check-menu"></label>
      <div class="burger-line first"></div>
      <div class="burger-line second"></div>
      <div class="burger-line third"></div>
      <div class="burger-line fourth"></div>
      <nav class="main-menu">
        <a href="#">Мобильные</a>
        <a href="#">Играть</a>
        <a href="#">Советы</a>
        <a href="#">Программы</a>
      </nav>
    </div>
    <!----------------/MOBILE MENU---------------------------->
  </div>
</div>
<!-----------------------/ШАПКА----------------------->

<div class="main">
  <div class="text_main">
    <p><img src="https://wallpapercave.com/wp/wp3110137.jpg"></p>
    <p>Lorem Ipsum - это текст-"рыба", часто используемый в печати и вэб-дизайне. Lorem Ipsum является стандартной "рыбой" для текстов на латинице с начала XVI века. В то время некий безымянный печатник создал большую коллекцию размеров и форм шрифтов, используя
      Lorem Ipsum для распечатки образцов. Lorem Ipsum не только успешно пережил без заметных изменений пять веков, но и перешагнул в электронный дизайн. Его популяризации в новое время послужили публикация листов Letraset с образцами Lorem Ipsum в 60-х
      годах и, в более недавнее время, программы электронной вёрстки типа Aldus PageMaker, в шаблонах которых используется Lorem Ipsum.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="banner">
    <a href="#"><img src="D:/Warhummer.jpg" alt="" width="468" height="60"></a>
  </div>
</div>

<!------------------ПОДВАЛ------------------>
<div class="footer">QBet.fun
  <div class="s1">QBet@gmail.com</div>
</div>
```